# Lesbesgue spaces involving time

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

If I have a function which lives in $f(x,t)\in L^2(0,T; H^{\frac{1}{2}})\cap L^{\infty}(0,T; L^2)$ for a certain time interval. I also know that $\partial_t \ f(x,t)\in L^{2}(0,T;H^{-1})$. Can I assure that the funtion lives in $ f(x,t)\in C(0,T ; L^2)$  this is continious in time which values in $L^2$??

It should be quite direct, but  I do not know how to prove it. Thanks in advanced.